# Replace string with custom values and iterate for all occurrences

Tags: python, perl, awk, sed

I am trying to replace some text in a file using either SED, PERL, AWK or a python script. I've tried a couple of things but can't seem to work it out.

I have the following in a text file called `data.txt`

```
&st=ALPHA&type=rec&uniId=JIM&acceptCode=123&drainNel=supp&
&st=ALPHA&type=rec&uniId=JIM&acceptCode=167&drainNel=supp&
&st=ALPHA&type=rec&uniId=SARA&acceptCode=231&drainNel=ured&
&st=ALPHA&type=rec&uniId=SARA&acceptCode=344&drainNel=iris&
&st=ALPHA&type=rec&uniId=SARA&acceptCode=349&drainNel=iris&
&st=ALPHA&type=rec&uniId=DAVE&acceptCode=201&drainNel=teef&
```

1) Script will take an input argument in the form of a number, e.g: `10000`

2) I want to replace all the text `ALPHA` with the given long number as arg and increment by 100 for e.g. if **uniId** is the same. If it is different it will increment by 5000 for e.g.

3) I want to replace all the **acceptCode** to change to the first **st** for all lines with the same **uniId**

> ./script 10000

.. still confused? Well, the final result could be this:

```
&st=10000&type=rec&uniId=JIM&acceptCode=10000&drainNel=supp&
&st=10100&type=rec&uniId=JIM&acceptCode=10000&drainNel=supp&
&st=15100&type=rec&uniId=SARA&acceptCode=15100&drainNel=ured&
&st=15200&type=rec&uniId=SARA&acceptCode=15100&drainNel=iris&
&st=15300&type=rec&uniId=SARA&acceptCode=15100&drainNel=iris&
&st=20300&type=rec&uniId=DAVE&acceptCode=20300&drainNel=teef&
```

This ^ should be REPLACED and applied to file `data.txt` - not just print on screen.

Comment: Honestly even with the example of what your aiming to get your question doesnt make much sense.

Comment: "ALPHA with a long number increment by 100" but you dont 'increment' in your example you are adding 2 zeros a random number.

Comment: If the description is confusing, I do apologise. I provided an end result to see where I am trying to get.

Comment: You want to replace 'ALPHA' with numbers? do the numbers represent any thing or just random?

Comment: Yes the number represent epoch time unix in milliseconds. So they need to go up from the first arg. But I am using example for simplification.

Comment: @JackHerer - This problem is almost unsolvable unfortunately!

Comment: this very far from unsolvable!!!!

Comment: With a little more info this is actually pretty simple

Comment: Looks pretty simple. I'll throw something together later today when I'm at a computer if it hasn't been solved yet. I just don't get where the 15X00  and 20300 is coming from though if you're starting with 10000.

Comment: I am not very good with regex but that may the best way to go with this

Comment: @melpomene, I have tried sed -i -e 's/\(st=\).\{13\}/\10100/2' data.txt, also perl -pi -e 's/\[st=ALPHA\10000([0-9]+)/3640+$1/e' data.txt | so tried a few things, but not quite what I expected...

Comment: As the downvote says, you have clearly not done any resaerch into this problem because you will find there are many ways to do this, I have just done what i think you need doing but I feel you should really spend some time trying to do it youself. apologies if i sound rude, i promise im not being rude, just following SO police to push at getting you to try harder it can be done and very easily with some learning

Comment: Something to get you started: `[i + DELIMITER for i in STRING.split(DELIMITER) if i]`

Comment: @Saffik I tried your Perl code and got `Unmatched ) in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/[st=ALPHA\10000([0-9]+) <-- HERE / at -e line 1.`

Comment: @Shawn - 10000 is starting value. Increment this by 100 for all lines with same uniId. If uniId changes to new one, then increment by 5000, keep incrementing by 100 for all subsequent lines with same uniId. Throughout we will keep track of st value.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see the 5000 part. My bad.

Comment: "This ^ should be REPLACED and applied to file data.txt"  --  be very careful here; that sounds dangerously like editing-in-place, which would complicate the problem a **lot**;  just output to a separate file, say, `data-with-numbers.txt`;  if you really need the final output file to be called `data.txt` for some reason, then rename the original `data.txt` and then rename `data-with-numbers.txt` to become `data.txt`  ... all this might go without saying, but I filled up a hard drive once, `grep`ing from an input file and appending the results to the same file "for convenience"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's one way, using awk (wrapped in a shell script for convenience because it's a bit too much for a one-liner):

```
#!/bin/sh
# Usage:
# $./transform.sh [STARTCOUNT] < data.txt > temp.txt
# $ mv -f temp.txt data.txt
awk  -F '&' -v "cnt=${1:-10000}" -v 'OFS=&' \
   'NR == 1 { ac = cnt; uni = $4; }
    NR > 1 && $4 == uni { cnt += 100 }
    $4 != uni { cnt += 5000; ac = cnt; uni = $4 }
    { $2 = "st=" cnt; $5 = "acceptCode=" ac; print }'
```

Running this on a file holding your sample input:

```
$ ./transform.sh 10000 < data.txt
&st=10000&type=rec&uniId=JIM&acceptCode=10000&drainNel=supp&
&st=10100&type=rec&uniId=JIM&acceptCode=10000&drainNel=supp&
&st=15100&type=rec&uniId=SARA&acceptCode=15100&drainNel=ured&
&st=15200&type=rec&uniId=SARA&acceptCode=15100&drainNel=iris&
&st=15300&type=rec&uniId=SARA&acceptCode=15100&drainNel=iris&
&st=20300&type=rec&uniId=DAVE&acceptCode=20300&drainNel=teef&
```

And a perl version that does an in-place edit of the input file:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -ani -F'&'
# Usage:
# $ ./transform.pl COUNT datafile
use warnings;
use strict;
use English;

our ($count, $a, $uni);

BEGIN {
  $count = shift @ARGV;
  die "Missing count argument" unless defined $count and $count =~ /^\d+$/;
  $ac = $count;
  $uni = "";
  $OFS = '&';
}

if ($NR == 1) {
  $uni = $F[3];
} elsif ($uni ne $F[3]) {
  $count += 5000;
  $ac = $count;
  $uni = $F[3];
} else {
  $count += 100;
}
$F[1] = "st=$count";
$F[4] = "acceptCode=$ac";
print @F;
```

Running it on your sample input:

```
$ ./transform.pl 10000 data.txt
$ cat data.txt
&st=10000&type=rec&uniId=JIM&acceptCode=10000&drainNel=supp&
&st=10100&type=rec&uniId=JIM&acceptCode=10000&drainNel=supp&
&st=15100&type=rec&uniId=SARA&acceptCode=15100&drainNel=ured&
&st=15200&type=rec&uniId=SARA&acceptCode=15100&drainNel=iris&
&st=15300&type=rec&uniId=SARA&acceptCode=15100&drainNel=iris&
&st=20300&type=rec&uniId=DAVE&acceptCode=20300&drainNel=teef&
```

Comment: Good answer. I like the first approach in awk. A couple of lines and job done. The perl approach is also good albeit I noticed it trims/removes the last " `&` " on the last line. I will take the awk approach as it is simpler!

Comment: one quick question. When I use the AWK script like: `./transform.sh 1539504910000 < data.txt > temp.txt`, it uses scientific notation eg: &st=1.5395e+12&type.... | The input is epoch time linux, any idea how to print and do it in normal numeric format? - I am trying somethings but if i can work it out :)

Comment: @Saffik awk numbers are floating point. I think there's a variable that controls how they're formatted when converted to a string.

Comment: solved by using gawk. Was using mawk by default. thanks alot buddy

Answer (score 1):

#### A few assumptions

Your requirement 2) I want to replace all the text ALPHA with the given long number as arg and increment by 100 for e.g. if uniId is the same. If it is different it will increment by 5000 for e.g._ in conjunction with your example output requires your input data to be **sorted on the uniId** field. If the file is not sorted, the 100 increments and the 5000 increments will not yield the desired initial values for each uniId

The increment scheme assumes that no one uniId value will have enough records to increment into the next 5000 range set for newly identified uniId values.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from collections import OrderedDict
import csv
import sys

class TrackingVars(object):
    """
    The TrackingVars class manages the business logic for maintaining the
    st field counters and the acctCode values for each uniId
    """

    def __init__(self, long_number):
        self.uniId_table = {}
        self.running_counter = long_number

    def __initial_value__(self):
        """
        The first encounter for a uniId will have st = acctCode
        """
        retval = (self.running_counter, self.running_counter)
        return retval

    def get_uniId(self, id):
        """
        A convenience method for returning uniId tracking values
        """
        curval, original_value = self.uniId_table.get(id, self.__initial_value__())
        return (curval, original_value)

    def track(self, uniId):
        """
        curval = original_value when a new uniId is encountered.
        If the uniId is known, simply increment curval by 100
        if the uniId is new and there is at least 1 key in the
        tracking table increment curval by 5000
        always update tracking variables
        """
        curval, original_value = self.get_uniId(uniId)
        if uniId in self.uniId_table.keys():
            curval = curval + 100
        else:
            if self.uniId_table:
                curval = curval + 5000
                original_value = curval
        self.running_counter = curval
        retval = (curval, original_value)
        self.uniId_table[uniId] = retval
        return retval


def data_lines(filename):
    """
    Read file as input delimited by &
    """
    with open(filename, "r", newline=None) as fin:
        csvin = csv.reader(fin, delimiter="&")
        for row in csvin:
            yield row

def transform_data_line(line):
    """
    Transform data into key, values pairs
    leading and traling & have no valid key, value pairs
    """
    head = ("head", None)
    tail = ("tail", None)
    items = [head]
    for field in line[1:-1]:
        key, value = field.split("=")
        items.append([key, value])
    retval = OrderedDict(items)
    retval["tail"] = tail
    return retval

def process_data_line(record, text_to_replace, tracking_vars):
    """
    if st value is ALPHA update record with tracking variables
    """
    st = record.get("st")
    if st is not None:
        if st == text_to_replace:
            uniId = record.get("uniId")
            curval, original_value = tracking_vars.track(uniId)
            record["st"] = curval
            record["acceptCode"] = original_value
    return record


def process_file():
    """
    Get the long number from the command line input.
    Initialize the tracking variables.
    Process each row of the file.
    """
    long_number = sys.argv[1]
    tracking_vars = TrackingVars(int(long_number))
    for row in data_lines("data.txt"):
        record = transform_data_line(row)
        retval = process_data_line(record, "ALPHA", tracking_vars)
        yield retval


def write(iter_in, filename_out):
    """
    Write each row from the iterator to the csv.
    make sure the first and last fields are empty.
    """
    with open(filename_out, "w", newline=None) as fout:
        csvout = csv.writer(fout, delimiter="&")
        for row in iter_in:
            encoded_row = ["{0}={1}".format(k, v) for k, v in row.items()]
            encoded_row[0]=""
            encoded_row[-1]=""
            csvout.writerow(encoded_row)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    write(process_file(), "data.new.txt")
```

#### Output

`$cat data.net.txt`

```
&st=10000&type=rec&uniId=JIM&acceptCode=10000&drainNel=supp&
&st=10100&type=rec&uniId=JIM&acceptCode=10000&drainNel=supp&
&st=15100&type=rec&uniId=SARA&acceptCode=15100&drainNel=ured&
&st=15200&type=rec&uniId=SARA&acceptCode=15100&drainNel=iris&
&st=15300&type=rec&uniId=SARA&acceptCode=15100&drainNel=iris&
&st=20300&type=rec&uniId=DAVE&acceptCode=20300&drainNel=teef&
```

#### Conclusion

Only you know why the business rules for the incrementing number scheme are the way they are. However having a control break on uniId and the st value dependent upon the previous uniId increment seems problematic to me. You could process unsorted files if each new uniId encountered would start at a new 5000 boundary. For example  15000, 2000, 25000, etc.

#### P.S

I love the AWK and Perl answers. They are simple and straight forward. They answer the question exactly as it was posed.  Now all we need is a SED example :)

Comment: Very useful code there. Appreciate it. You sir, are a genius.

Answer (score 0):

just bit more efficient control, in one line gnu awk:

```
awk  -F\& -vi=10000 -vOFS=\& '{if(NR==1) { ac=i; u=$4; } else { if($4==u) i+=100; else { i+=5000; ac=i; u=$4; } }; $2="st=" i; $5 =gensub(/[0-9]+/,ac,1,$5); print } ' data.txt
```

accept any various string on 5th field.. Thank Shawn.

Comment: Please elaborate why it's more efficient.